# In Asp.net mvc EF can i use code first and db first at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-database-first

So i have a project working with entityframework code first and everything is fine, but now i need to read some data from another database, i just want to read form it and don't want to modify it in anyway. Forgive me if the title is misleading but that what came to my mind

Thanks in advace

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can have both Entity Framework approaches in same asp.net MVC project, all you need to do is create a separate new entity model with Database first approach as selection.